# Laravel 5.4 with MySQL 8 migration error

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, laravel-artisan, artisan-migrate

I have cloned a laravel 5.4 project to my Mac which has MySQL 8 installed and whenever I try to run `php artisan migrate` I receive the following error:

[image]

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/23961

Comment: I find it really useful, but I actually downgraded to MySQL 5.7 and it worked like a charm

Answer (score 3):

Set the user back to mysql_native_password for mysql verison 8.0

```
mysql -u root - p
```

then

```
ALTER USER 'forge'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'new_password';
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL 8.0.4 changed default authentication  `mysql_native_password` to `caching_sha2_password`

```
mysqld.exe --initialize-insecure --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
```

this going to initialize your data directory with root user without a password with `mysql_native_password` which laravel actually works.